# Invoking powershell cmdlet from C++

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with a C++ project. I want to execute a `"Set-SmbServerConfiguration –EncryptData $true"` cmdlet from my c++ code.

I tried with system() but its not working. May be its getting stuck at confirm option after executing command as follow:

```
Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing operation 'Modify' on Target 'SMB Server Configuration'.
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Is there any way to do this with default confirmation value("Y") from c++ code in windows?

Comment: Maybe you need to pass `-Force`? `-Confirm` default value is `false` anyway.

Comment: -Force is also not helping. `system("start powershell.exe Set-SmbServerConfiguration –EncryptData $true -Force");`

Comment: Not sure if it is your issue here, but consider passing `-NoProfile` as well. I would consider that good measure when "programmatically" invoking PS so that the command runs agnostic to any settings a user may have.

Comment: Appended `-NoProfile` to existing system statement but still `EncryptData` value is not getting updated. `system("start powershell.exe Set-SmbServerConfiguration –EncryptData $true -Confirm:$false -NoProfile");`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding confirm:$false to the poweshell

Comment: Tried below command but " EncryptData" value is not not getting updated. `system("start powershell.exe Set-SmbServerConfiguration –EncryptData $true -Confirm:$false");`

Comment: If I run command `Set-SmbServerConfiguration –EncryptData $true -Confirm:$false` from powershell ISE with admin access then it works but not sure why its not working from c++ code using system command.

Answer (score 0):

Running program with admin access resolved the issue, with below command: `system("start powershell.exe Set-SmbServerConfiguration –EncryptData $true -Confirm:$false");`